# Having a module class with the same name as a top level class: 'expected module_classe_file to define top_level class'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My apps/model folder looks like that:

```
models/
  module/
    category.rb
  category.rb
```

But I can't seem to find a way to correctly autoload module/category: I always have the error `Expected /app/models/module/category.rb to define Category`.

As of now I only see two options: not adding it to autoloading, or renaming `module/category.rb` to `module/module_category.rb`, neither seems like a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best thing to do in your case is to add the`module/category.rb` into the `lib` directory.

1. Grab the code from `category.rb` and create a `lib/category.rb` file.
2. Then include your module code into your `app/models/category.rb`
3. In `application.rb` be sure to load the `lib` directory `config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib`.

   ```
   class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
     include Category
   ```

I personally would not do it this way though. The naming gets confusing imo. Have you tried namespacing your code?

For example, you could try this too:

```
  models/
    category/
       category_something.rb #change the name of the file to something else
    category.rb
```

Then in your `category_something.rb`

```
class Category::CategorySomething
   #code code code
end
```

And then that way you can use the code like a module.

Comment: Thanks. This is a big module with many models, it's used for api calls, so I thought his place was in /models rather than in /lib. I talked about renaming the file to /module/module_category.rb in my question, but I hoped there was a less ugly way of doing it

Comment: Oh yes, you did talk about it in the question :). Well that's the only way I know how to do that. Maybe someone will come along with something better. Anyways if you go with the `lib` route don't forget to load it into your app. `config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib`. I'll update the answer.